# Google Kubernetes Engine denying traffic

Tags: http, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-mvc, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a google Kubernetes Engine running. I made an ASP.NET core MVC application that is deployed as a service on the engine and I would like to be able to make an HTTP request (`GET http:serviceendpointip/controller/action`) to this service from a different application. I tested my MVC application using ngrok (provides a public url to my application) and the request worked successfully.

So my application seems to be working fine. However, when I deploy it as an exposed public service to the Kubernetes engine, the request is not working and I am assuming that the engine is somehow blocking this network traffic... I am able to view the application's homepage on `http://serviceendpointip/home` from a web browser. What could be causing my HTTP request to be failing?

Running `kubectl describe deployment telebot-pianomoves-v1-km`:

```
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Tue, 28 Aug 2018 21:34:03 +1000
Labels:                 run=telebot-pianomoves-v1-km
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision=12
                        kubernetes.io/change-cause=kubectl set image 
deployment/telebot-pianomoves-v1-km telebot-pianomoves-v1- 
km=gcr.io/telebot-pianomoves-v1/tel
ebot-pianomoves-v1-km:20180907t124111 --record=true --kubeconf...
Selector:               run=telebot-pianomoves-v1-km
Replicas:               3 desired | 2 updated | 4 total | 1 available | 3 
unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  1 max unavailable, 1 max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=telebot-pianomoves-v1-km
  Containers:
   telebot-pianomoves-v1-km:
    Image:        gcr.io/telebot-pianomoves-v1/telebot-pianomoves-v1- 
   km:20180907t124111
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      False   MinimumReplicasUnavailable
OldReplicaSets:  telebot-pianomoves-v1-km-7775cfb674 (1/1 replicas 
created), telebot-pianomoves-v1-km-cf4f5d9d8 (1/1 replicas created)
NewReplicaSet:   telebot-pianomoves-v1-km-7b78d6597d (2/2 replicas 
created)
Events:          <none>
```

Running `kubectl get deployments`:

`telebot-pianomoves-v1-km   3         4         2            1           9d`

Thanks

Comment: Post `kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>`, and `kubectl get deployments`

Comment: I am getting the error `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`, I am running the command from the cloud shell in the console and found `<deployment-name>` from "Service Details". That error occurs for the other command too.

Comment: Did you configure `kubectl`? You can copy `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` on your master  to `~/.kube/config` on your cloud shell

Comment: When I run the command `kubectl cluster-info` from cloud shell, I get `Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`. What gcloud command do I have to run to achieve what you said?

Comment: It's not configured correctly.

Comment: How do I configure kubectl for Google Kubernetes Engine?

Comment: It's not clear how you programmed the service but you will need to configure a firewall rule to permit external traffic to it. GCP permits internal traffic and ssh by default which is why ngrok (because it tunnels over ssh) works.

Comment: @HarryStuart like I mentioned: You can copy /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf on your master to ~/.kube/config on your cloud shell

Comment: or your cloud shell might be ssh proxying to your cluster, but not sure. are you running GKE?

Comment: I am publishing the MVC app from Visual Studio to Kubernetes Engine and selecting "expose as a service" and "make service public". Why would I need a firewall exception?

Comment: I am not sure how to"copy /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf on your master to ~/.kube/config on your cloud shell", I am new to this sorry

Comment: ssh to one of the masters and run `cat /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` then copy the output to your clipboard. Then on your cloud shell run `cat << EOF > ~/.kube/config\n  <the output> \n EOF` . the `\n` chars mean a newline

Comment: Great, I’ve configured kubectl. See question update.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix my issue. I did so by publishing to Kubernetes Engine from Visual Studio and making sure I set the number of replicas to 1.